# Secure Ajax Requests made by YII

Tags: php, ajax, security, yii

i'm currently writing a Application based on YII.
My action for index:

```
  public function actionIndex() {
    $data = array();
    $data['server'] = Server::model()->findByPk(1);
    $data['dataProvider'] = new CActiveDataProvider('ServerUserPermission', array('criteria' => array('condition' => 'serverID=:id', 'params' => array(':id' => 1))));
    $this->render('index', $data);
}
```

my ajax action:

```
public function actionAddPermission($server) {
    if(Util::checkServerPower($server, Permission::MODIFY_SERVER)) {
        $perm = new ServerUserPermission;
        $perm->userID = 1;
        $perm->serverID = $server;
        $perm->power = 10;
        try {
            if ($perm->save()) {
                echo "OK";
            } else {
                echo Util::print_r($perm->getErrors());
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Critical Error Code: ' . $e->getCode();
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No Permissions';
    }
}
```

My view links to the addPermission action by using a button:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton("Insert New Player", array('addPermission', 'server' => $server->serverID), array('success'=>'refresh'));
```

My function Util::checkServerPower(...) checks the current User of the Application. Consequence: Ajax requests in YII are handled by an Guest AuthWeb User, but i need to check whether the User is actually allowed to add permissions or not. I currently cannot think of a secured solution to protect malicious data send by other guests or not. Is it somehow possible to get the (server-side) userID of the Ajax-call?

Thanks anyway
sincerly

Comment: AJAX requests carry session information just like any other request and Yii should recognize the user without you needing to do anything special. If your AJAX requests appear to come from a guest when the user is in fact logged in you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Oh dear, i just relogged with current user, which fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it by using the built in access control and [extending CWebUser](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/60/).
It might seem lengthy but I think it's a clean solution. (We already have Yii::app()->user->isGuest and the like, so why not check all permissions here?)

#### 1) Activate the access control filter.

(In one controller or in /components/controller.php for all your controllers at once)

```
public function filters()
{
    return array( 'accessControl' ); // Tell Yii to use access rules for this controller
}
```

#### 2) Add an access rule

In the concerned controller. (Sorry, I didn't bother with your index-action.)

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        [
            'allow', 
            'actions'=>['AddPermission'], 
            'expression'=>'$user->has(Permission::MODIFY_SERVER)'
        ],
        ['deny'],  // Deny everything else. 
    );
}
```

#### 3) Extend CWebUser

```
// components/WebUser.php
class WebUser extends CWebUser {
    public function has( $permission)
    {
            // Check database for permissions using Yii::app()->user->id
            ...
    }
}
```

#### 4) Configure your app to use your new WebUser instead of CWebUser

```
// config/main.php
'components'=>[
    'user'=>[
        'class' => 'WebUser',
    ],
],
```

Comment: I am checking most of the Permissions by the built-in rbac and my Util method is basically just a shortcut to check if the User's power is greater or equal the given integer, but thanks anyway.

Comment: This is not the Answer i was looking for, but i found the solution myself, so take this cookie :)